# Linking .dll MinGW C++

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

I have a dynamic library (.dll) and its header (.h). In my code, I include the header, and try to build it through MinGW, using the command

```
g++ main.cpp lib.dll lib.h
```

but I get an undefined reference. How to link dynamic libraries correctly in the absence of `.a`/`.lib`?

This is the output:

```
g++ -l coupi  main.cpp -I D:/Development/Trash/test -L D:/Development/Trash/test
C:\Users\N\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6287BE.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `getFunction1[abi:cxx11]()' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you created the DLL? or is it a thirdparty one? Can you tell us which DLL it is? whoever created it should have created a lib/a file unless you are meant to dynamically load it... I think more info is needed to help you.

Comment: `g++ -l coupi  main.cpp -I D:/Development/Trash/test -L D:/Development/Trash/test` is certainly not the output of `g++ main.cpp lib.dll lib.h`. Please correct your question.